# Pulling the string value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

So I have this unordered list of items that is made from querying a mysql database

```
    <ul>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>pear</li>
    </ul>
```

I want there to be an onclick event that will pass 'apple' when I click apple and 'orange' when I click orange.

I also want to pass this information to another page through php. So this is my idea for the javascript function.

```
<script>
function passName(obj){
var pass = "<?php $x= " + obj.getName() + " ?>";
}

function getname(obj){
return 'string';
}
</script>
```

My Question: is there a method that exists within JavaScript that allows me to pull the raw string value of my unorderedlist without writing my own function? If I have to write my own JavaScript function, is there a way to set the 'name' strings automatically, while the list is populating?

Comment: "allows me to pull the raw string value of my unorderedlist" get the innerText of the `<ul>`. "set the 'name' strings automatically, while the list is populating" . What strings are you referring to? `var pass = "<?php $x= " + obj.getName() + " ?>";` will never work - you fundamentally mis-understand how the web works. That code will execute _before_ your page loads, which is when PHP was executing. Then your HTTP request ended and it stopped. If you want PHP to execute again you have to make another request to the server - either through a postback or an ajax request, and send your data in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use JQUERY [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for send data into php page

```js
/* Get value from clicked li */
 $(function() {

  let value = "";

  $('ul li').on("click", function() {

   value = $(this).text();
   console.log(value);
  });

  /* AJAX for send value into result.php page */

  $.post("result.php", {value: value}, function(res) {

   console.log(res); // return from result.php page 
  }); 

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>apple</li>
<li>orange</li>
<li>pear</li>
</ul>
```

**result.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value'])) {

        echo $_POST['value'];
    }
```

Comment: this assumes OP is using jquery. That's fine I guess but you should make it clear since the question doesn't mention it

Comment: HI, thanks for you reply. I would like to understand this code more; I'm a bit new to jquery and javascript. I understand your calling the Ajax library from the url, but I want to understand what is going on after the 'let value' command

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it. On click you can change the page or do whatever you want. In the new url you can append the fruit value as a parameter to pass it to php

```
    <ul>
       <li onclick="fruitsClick('apple')">apple</li>
       <li onclick="fruitsClick('orange')">orange</li>
       <li onclick="fruitsClick('pear')">pear</li>
    </ul>

<script>
function fruitsClick(fruit){
       // do whatever you want  
       window.location.href = "[yourpageurl]?fruit=" + fruit
}
</script>
```