# I'm trying to understand what is happening with this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php

I submitted a question a while back

[Pulling the string value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144849/pulling-the-string-value-in-javascript/48144966#48144966)

One of the answers to my questions was a code snippet that worked. However, when I attempted to replicate it on my XAMPP setup, it did not work.

```
/* Get value from clicked li */
$(function() {

    let value = "";

    $('ul li').on("click", function() {

        value = $(this).text();
        console.log(value);
    });

    /* AJAX for send value into result.php page */

    $.post("result.php", {value: value}, function(res) {

        console.log(res); // return from result.php page 
    }); 

});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>apple</li>
<li>orange</li>
<li>pear</li>
</ul>
```

with a result.php

```
if(isset($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value'])) {

    echo $_POST['value'];
}
```

(Note: this original answer was submitted by an Aman Kumar.)

I just want to understand:

- What is going on with this code, and
- where these bits of code should be going (in terms of HTML, PHP, and Javascript Files)

Comment: additionally, for a personal server, is it safe or efficient to be referring to google's AJAX Api?

Comment: This bit of code does not look like it will work anyway. The $.post method is called as the page loads before there are any values inside the `value` variable

Comment: On the original question, Aman submitted it as a code snippet, and it ran as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Whats going on with the code?

#### Short answer (tl;dr)

- You will get your list displayed
- Empty string will be sent to `result.php`
- Clicking on any list items (`apple`, `orange`, `pear`) will do nothing (other than assign what you click to `value` variable and log what you clicked to the console)

#### Long answer

You seem like you are new to (at least) JavaScript/jQuery/PHP --- so I will try and break this down with as many references as possible, so you can investigate deeper on your own.

You are declaring a block scope local variable using the Javascript keyword [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and initializing it to, well, an empty string.

**Note:**
`let` is different from `var`. To know more about the difference between the two and how they impact the logic, refer to Mozilla's documentation on a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

Then, in your `li` ([item in a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)) of `ul` ([unordered list of items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)), you monitor a user's click, by [attaching an event handler function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for the `click` event ---

```
$('ul li').on("click", function() {
```

The *attaching* functionality is provided by jQuery, which you include using the script tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Upon a click, you assign the value of the item (the string inside `<li>` and `</li>`) to `value` variable.

Your [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) (jQuery shorthand) pretty much passes an empty string to `result.php` page --- because no matter how many times you click on any of your list items, the `$.post` is not going to trigger---it ONLY fires **once** and that is at page load...

If you intend on passing the value of the list item that the user clicks on to `result.php`, then you must bring `$.post` within the friendly confines of the `click` event, as such:

```
$(function() {

    let value = "";

    $('ul li').on("click", function() {

        value = $(this).text();
        console.log(value);

        /* AJAX for send value into result.php page */

        $.post("result.php", {value: value}, function(res) {
            console.log(res); // return from result.php page 
        }); 
    });

});
```

Doing so, will trigger the sending of `value` to `result.php` each time a user clicks on  any list items (`apple`, `orange`, `pear`)

Lastly, there is your `result.php` which basically first checks for two things, using the [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statement:

1. Is `value` being posted and if so
2. It is not empty (which you could simply do `$_POST['value'] != ''`, by the way)

And, if the above two conditions are met, it simply echos the `value`

### Where should these bits of code reside?

**Simple answer:** It really depends.

If you have a simple/small (note, both these terms are *subjective*!) then having them all in one place (i.e. ONE `index.html` file with `CSS` and `JavaScript`) is *okay*.

However, if you have lengthy (again, subjective!) code, then breaking it down to its own respective files would be ideal.

General rule of thumb I like to follow myself:

> - If the code gets hard to navigate (i.e. too much scrolling), at that point, I simply break it down to its own pieces. OR
> - If I am doing a quick PoC (Proof of Concept), then I don't care if its one file or not

If you *do* break the code down into its own respective fragments, then it would look like this (again, names would differ... this is just an example):

`main.css`

```
ul li {
    ...
}
```

`main.js`

```
$(function() {

    let value = "";

    $('ul li').on("click", function() {

        value = $(this).text();
        console.log(value);

        /* AJAX for send value into result.php page */

        $.post("result.php", {value: value}, function(res) {
            console.log(res); // return from result.php page 
        }); 
    });

});
```

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>My Awesome HTML Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="My Awesome Project summary goes here... this will help Google/other search engines describe what this is all about!">
    <meta name="author" content="Rushikumar">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>apple</li>
      <li>orange</li>
      <li>pear</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lastly, your `result.php` fragment is fine as is... no further breaking down needs happening. However, your `result.php` file should look like this:

`result.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value'])) {
    echo $_POST['value'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You are correct to say that i am new to Javascript and JQuery. So my question is; should there be a another file created for the function? what type of file should it be?

Comment: @LouisCarmichael added the necessary info; recheck my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the ajax call inside the click handler

```
$('ul li').on("click", function() {

  const value = $(this).text();

  /* AJAX for send value into result.php page */
  $.post("result.php", {
    value: value
  }, function(res) {
    console.log(res); // return from result.php page 
  });
});
```